# Filter specific Notifications in Gnome 3.34.2

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, notifications

generally I like the notifications in gnome. But there is one notification which annoys me really badly.

I use the gnome extension "caffeine", which disables auto suspend. Each time I enable caffeine I get a notification for auto-suspension and screensaver is disabled. This also happens when I put videos in full-screen. I wish to disable this very specific notification.

Solutions I have found thus far mostly disable all notifications or at least all notifications from specific applications.

I am running the latest version of pop_os which is ubuntu based, using gnome 3.34.2

Answer (score 4):

If you have Gnome Tweaks, go to the extension option in that and modify settings. Else, you can do it in your browser, if you have Gnome Shell Extension installed.