# How can I filter notifications?

Tags: d-bus, notifications, gsettings

I am using Bodhi Linux, an Ubuntu derivative which, in my experience, for most purposes (but not all) works the same as Ubuntu.

I mean to filter notifications that show up in the desktop (inspired by [Cannot suppress notification when a client connects to my vino server VNC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698478/cannot-suppress-notification-when-a-client-connects-to-my-vino-server-vnc)).

How can I do that?

I meant to try something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/351776/226614), with `dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" ...`, but when tab-completing `gsettings get org.freedesktop` I only get `gsettings get org.freedesktop.ColorHelper`.
When tab-completing

```
$ ll /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.fre
org.freedesktop.ColorHelper.service         org.freedesktop.secrets.service
org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Secret.service  org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
```

I am not sure this means the dbus-way is not feasible.
I don't know how to find if it is, and if so, how to find the appropriate command.

I tried

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

just as a first test, the `vino-server` notifications kept popping.

This is the notification applet I have (I did not figure out which is yet).
I am not sure any filtering can be done at that level, other than selecting which are shown (Low/Normal/Critical).
So far this did not help, even deselecting all levels, the notifications pop-up. So at least from this simple test, I wouldn't know in which cases these checkboxes work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just tabcompleting `org.`?

[an answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564341/filter-specific-notifications-in-gnome-3-34-2) might help:

> If you have Gnome Tweaks, go to the extension option in that and modify settings. Else, you can do it in your browser, if you have Gnome Shell Extension installed.

Comment: Do you mean tab-completing `org.` just to see what is available?
The link you provided *might* help in cases where notifications come from a Gnome Shell Extension. This is not the case.